# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

I am trying to detect objects with Tensorflow 2.x. But I encountered such a problem during training. My data is in .jpg and .jpeg extension. Tensorflow doesn't train pictures with .jpg extension, do you know? How do you think I can solve this error?

Comment: pls, post your code along with the complete error traceback log. I don't think .jpg is an issue, maybe related to code in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Tensor does work with jpg extensions. I use them all the time. I was not sure if it will except jpeg as an extension even though the file format is the same so I tried it using the ImageDataGenerator and it works as well. So apparently you have some other type of problem. I suggest you use the code below to iterate through your directories and check that the files are valid image files and have either jpg or jpeg extensions

```
import os
import PIL
from PIL import Image
source_dir=r'c:\temp\spiders\storage'
source_list=os.listdir (source_dir)
for file in source_list:
    fpath=os.path.join(source_dir, file)
    try:
        img=Image.open(fpath)
        shape=img.size
        if file.endswith('jpeg') or file.endswith( 'jpg'):
            pass
        else:
            print ('file ', fpath, ' has an extension other than jpg or jpeg')
    except:
        print ('file ', fpath, ' is an invalid image file')
print ('***** process completed *****')
```